# Figuring out the constness of an object within its destructor

Tags: c++, constants, destructor

I have a class Stuff, with two functions foo (const and non-const):

```
class Stuff
{
public:
    ~Stuff() { foo(); }

    void foo() const { cout << "const foo" << endl; }
    void foo()       { cout << "non-const foo" << endl; }
};
```

Here's what I am trying to do:

1. If the stuff was const, call const foo in the destructor of Stuff.
2. if the stuff wasn't const, call non-const foo in the destructor of Stuff.

I was hoping that just defining the destructor as shown above would work, but it turns out that the constness is stripped away right before executing the destructor (it is enforced right after the constructor completes, so I cannot set any flag there either). To make it clearer, here's an example:

```
{ Stuff stuff; }
{ const Stuff cstuff; }
```

This code prints "non-const foo" twice. I want it to print "non-const foo", followed by "const foo". Is that possible with C++?

EDIT: A few people are asking for more context. In the real code, stuff is basically a handle to some data. If stuff is accessed in a non-const manner, I assume that the data has been modified, so I need to communicate that to other processes (MPI) using the foo function (after I am done modifying it -> in the destructor, when I release the handle). If it was accessed in a const-manner, I know I don't need to transfer anything, so I am calling non-const foo, that does nothing.

Comment: The destructor destroys the object, by definition it's not const. Const only applies if you are calling `stuff.foo()` or `cstuff.foo()`.

Comment: It's not possible to detect whether the object is `const` in the constructor or destructor. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It is not const both in the constructor and the destructor. You want to know in the constructor if it will be, and in the destructor if it was. Strange

Comment: As per your edit: It sounds as though you are trying to implement transactional semantics of some kind. Would it perhaps make sense to keep track of whether state was modified using a flag (which only gets set on the mutable code-path), and implementing the conditional behavior in the destructor based on whether this flag was toggled?

Comment: It sounds to me like you might want two different types, `MutableStuff` and `ImmutableStuff`.

Comment: Creating two different types is not an option here, as Stuff is already heavily used in the code base.
The mutable code-path is extremely performance sensitive (bracket operator). I can't add a flag in there. Would it be possible to have some other class that would somehow observe Stuff, and call bar(const Stuff) or bar(Stuff) right after construction is done? It could then set a flag between construction and destruction, when the const semantics is valid. ?

Comment: @Touloudou You're going to have to audit the code base anyway to make sure that `const` is never cast away. Perhaps add a helper function that constructs a `const Stuff` for you and use that in code paths that are audited to be assured not to modify the object. But two objects is a better idea -- that will ensure that a  `const Stuff` is never accidentally modified.

Comment: What about simply storing an extra flag to specify which `foo()` to call?  Or wrapping the handle inside a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that calls the appropriate `foo()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> [...] `const` and `volatile`
>   semantics (7.1.6.1) are not applied on an object under destruction. They stop being in effect when the
>   destructor for the most derived object (1.8) starts.

12.4/2 [class.dtor] in N4141.

So no, this is not possible.

Comment: But note that you still can call `static_cast<const Stuff&>(*this).foo()` to call the const versions of functions.

Comment: @Artyer But you'd have to know whether or not you want to, which appears to be the core of the question.

Comment: And in other methods? Is it possible to determine the constancy of the created object from inside the class in principle?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka In normal member functions, you can overload based on constness, as is demonstrated in OP.

Comment: Can I somehow find out that the object is created with "const" and change the implementation of the constructor for this case?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka No, constructors have basically the same clause I quoted here, see 12.1/3.